# Save and Insert video to gallery on Android 10

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-mediascanner, android-10.0

I'm trying to save a video to the gallery,the following code works well an all Android versions except the **Android Q**:

```
private void getPath() {
    String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    contentValues.put(
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, 
        "Movies/" + "Folder");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
    Uri collection = 
        MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    Uri videoUri = resolver.insert(collection, contentValues);
    if (videoUri != null) {
        try (ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(videoUri, "w", null)) {
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            if (pfd != null) {
                outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(videoUri);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    contentValues.clear();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
    if (videoUri != null) {
        resolver.update(videoUri, contentValues, null, null);
    }
    } else {
        File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
            + "/Folder");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File videoFile = new File(storageDir, videoFileName);
            savedVideoPath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using get `getExternalFilesDir()` , but doesn't work, no video created in the gallery

```
String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    File imageFile = null;
    File storageDir = new File(
        getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
        "Folder");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        imageFile = new File(storageDir, videoFileName);
    }
    savedVideoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

I use a 3rd-party library to record `SurfaceView`, this library requires a path to save the recorded video :

```
 mRenderPipeline = EZFilter.input(this.effectBmp)
                    .addFilter(new GalleryEffects().getEffect(VideoMaker.this, i))
                    .enableRecord(savedVideoPath, true, false)
                    .into(mRenderView);
```

When record video finished, the recorded video saved with the given path `savedVideoPath` , everything works just fine on all android version except the **Android Q**

After saving the video, when I check, I get an empty video in the gallery

[image]

Comment: Where is your fileOutputStream? In above code you're just making an directory and a file.

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri thank you for your comment,actually, I want to create a path to use it

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri can you please check the question again,I have updated it

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Did you find the solution??

Comment: @ParagPawar , just a temporary solution I ended this by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside the `Application` tag

Answer (score 10):

I have answered you to your other post to... You need an inputstream (file, bitmap etc.)  and write an outputstream from the inputfile.

You have to change the library to make it work with Android Q . If you cannot do this you could copy the video to the media gallery and then delete the old video created in getExternalFilesDir(). After this you have the uri of the video and can do what you want with the uri

If you have saved the video with getExternalFilesDir() you could use my example here : The media uri you get is "uriSavedVideo" . This is only an example. A large video should also be copied in the background.

```
String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

ContentValues valuesvideos;
valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "Folder");
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
valuesvideos.put(
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, 
    System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
Uri collection = 
    MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

try {
    pfd = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    // Get the already saved video as fileinputstream from here
    File storageDir = new File(
        mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), 
        "Folder");
    File imageFile = new File(storageDir, "Myvideo");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    pfd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

valuesvideos.clear();
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
mContext.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
```

Comment: Can I access this saved video file with any File Manager app?

Comment: is there any way to do it without copying?

Comment: What do you mean ? Recording a video and inserting it directly into the media store ?

Comment: Look at [this code example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) from the Android Docs. You have to use `VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY` instead of `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for Android Q.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 5):

> I want to create a path to use it

You are getting a `Uri` from `MediaStore`. There is no "path". Not only can a `Uri` not be converted to a path, but you do not have filesystem access to that location on Android 10 and higher.

Get rid of this:

```
        if (videoUri != null) {
            savedVideoPath = getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);
        }
```

as it will not work.

Replace it with your code to write out your video to the location identified by the `Uri`. Use `resolver.openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` to that location. In particular, do this *before* you call `resolver.update()` for an `IS_PENDING` of `0`, as that specifically says "I am done writing to the `Uri`; you can use the content now".

Or, use one of the filesystem locations that you *do* have access to, such as `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`, and get rid of the `MediaStore` stuff.

Comment: if Mark had a penny for every question he answered with "Use resolver.openOutputStream()", he would have been the richest man on the globe.

Comment: @pic: "can you please tell me how I can I get location from OutputStream" -- I do not know what you mean by this, sorry.

Comment: how to move saved file in `getExternalFilesDir` to public DCIM or Movies folder using MediaStore?