# How to create a video file path on Android 10

Tags: java, android, storage, mediastore, android-10.0

I tried  to create a video file path as the follows :

```
String fileName =   videoFileName = "VID" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

public static String createVideoPath(Context context, String fileName) {
    File imageThumbsDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir("FOLDER");
    if (imageThumbsDirectory != null) {
        if (!imageThumbsDirectory.exists()) {
            imageThumbsDirectory.mkdir();
        }
    }
    String appDir = context.getExternalFilesDir("FOLDER").getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(appDir, fileName);
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I call the method above like this : `String videoPath = createVideoPath(getApplicationContext(),fileName);`

I use this [library](https://github.com/uestccokey/EZFilter) for edits :

```
EZFilter.input(mainBitmap).addFilter(null).enableRecord(videoPath, true, false).into(renderView);
```

After the edit finished, I try to save the final video to the gallery as follows :

```
private static Uri publicDirURI(Context context, String fileName, String dir) {
        ContentValues valuesVideos;
        valuesVideos = new ContentValues();
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, dir);
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        valuesVideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesVideos);
        return saveFileToPublicMovies(context, valuesVideos, uriSavedVideo, fileName);
    }


private static Uri saveFileToPublicMovies(Context context, ContentValues contentValues, Uri uriSavedVideo, String fileName) {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
    try {
        pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        if (pfd != null) {
            out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            File videoFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("FOLDER"), fileName);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            pfd.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    contentValues.clear();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
    context.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, contentValues, null, null);
    return uriSavedVideo;
}
```

But I always get an empty saved video with 0.00b, I've tried the app with device running Android 9, but with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, and everyting works just fine, so the issue is not related with the library.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue, I'm stuck on it almost 1 week, thank you

**Edit :**

```
 private static Uri saveFileToPublicMovies(Context context, ContentValues contentValues, Uri uriSavedVideo, String fileName) {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
        try {
            pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            if (pfd != null) {
                out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
                File videoFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("AppName"), fileName);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.getFD().sync();
                out.close();
                in.close();
                pfd.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        contentValues.clear();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
        context.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, contentValues, null, null);
```

Comment: "I always get an empty saved video with 0.00b" -- how are you determining this? Have you tried using `openOutputStream()`, rather than `openFileDescriptor()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your comment, when I use openOutputStream() the saved video out with the right size, but still unplayable, it's showing like corrupted video

Comment: Add `out.flush();` and `out.getFD().sync();` before `out.close();`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, unfortunately, the same, I've edit my question with your answer, please check it

Comment: Sorry, I suggested `out.getFD().sync()`, not `in.getFD().sync()`.

Comment: @CommonsWaresorry for disturb, but the same again, I edit my question

Comment: @CommonsWare, When I go to File Manager app > Android > data > App Package Name > Files > Movies, I can see the video playable and with right size, I do not know why it's showing as corrupted in the gallery

Comment: It is possible that the gallery app that you are using is not paying attention to `IS_PENDING`.

Comment: I test this answer and it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056240/7505033