# How to save an audio file using MediaStore API

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-storage, mediastore, android-external-storage

I want to download an audio file from firebase storage and then save it in the device so that any other app or music player (and my app later) can access and play.

The [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) says that all Shareable media files (images, audio files, videos) should be saved using [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) API, but i couldn't find anything useful on how to do that.

Also i want the file to be located on a persistent location such as MyApp/Audio so that when user navigates through file explorer they can find it as well.

Please provide me a complete example on how to do that.

I tried to apply the [example from the documentaion](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) as following:

```
private fun createFile() {
    val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

    val audioCollection =
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 28) VOLUME_EXTERNAL else VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

    val newSongDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "My Song.mp3")
    }

    val myFavoriteSongUri = resolver.insert(audioCollection, newSongDetails)

    if(myFavoriteSongUri == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "myFavoriteSongUri is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    val path = myFavoriteSongUri.path

    if(path == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "path is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    downloadFile(File(path))
}

private fun downloadFile(file: File) {
    val url = "example url"
    val ref = Firebase.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url)
    ref.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File downloaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

First, The documentation says On API <= 28, use VOLUME_EXTERNAL instead of VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY, but when i used the code below android studio showed me warning says that VOLUME_EXTERNAL requires API level 29.

Second, when i run the code, app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: It looks as if your downloaded file is already saved as where would  you use `file: File` for else?

Comment: Further you can find examples if you read pages tagged 'mediastore'. The second one (first one after yours) is very usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222644/contentresolver-query-doesnt-return-the-newly-inserted-video

Comment: @blackapps I want to know how to get the file uri that will be passed to downloadFile method.

Comment: Well you see that exactly in the example i gave you: `val newVideoUri = resolver
        .insert(videoCollection, newVideoDetails)`. THIS IS NO FILE URI!!! It is a content scheme uri. You will have to adapt your download function of course. Look for a Firebase function to download to an OutputStream.

Comment: @blackapps see edited answer please.

Comment: `val path = myFavoriteSongUri.path` That is not usable.

Comment: `downloadFile(File(path))` That is nonsense. I told you before that it is no file uri and that you had to adapt your downloadFile function. You did not adapt it.

Comment: @blackapps Can you answer the question with the right code please?