# How to move a file from my app's internal storage to the phone's download directory in Android Q (10)?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11

It seems that `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is now deprecated, so I need an alternative.

Say I have file the `foo.png` in my app's internal storage. I can easily access this file with

```
val foo = File(context.filesDir, "foo.png")
```

My problem is that I want to move this file to the user's Downloads directory, so that they can see it on their phone.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815103/11848486) uses `DownloadManager`. Unfortunately this is an image I generate myself, not download from somewhere.

Comment: For an Android 20 device: Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file and you can copy your file to that external storage location in the old way. After that delete original.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm aware of that. It seems that is only a temporary solution. I'm looking for the long term solution.

Comment: Then why didnt you say so?

Comment: This was actually answered by user Frank in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57940502/11848486).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Use Storage Acces Framework to let the user choose the Download directory .

Use MediaStore to insert file to Download directory.