# getting content uri of already downloaded video in android Q

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

i still don't understand the change made on access media files in android Q. My app downloads videos, but playing or retrieving the video gives error.

Noticed, for android Q, every media file outside of app specific folders need to be registered in the contentresolver. In which the content resolver gives a special id to that file in return. Am i right?

if so how do i register a media file in content resolver and at the same time get the uri of the media file

A good explanation on accessing, saving and opening media files on android Q will be appreciated for a better understanding

Comment: Please read stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`. And dont talk about contentresolver but about the MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

The file manipulation changes from android 9 (Q) are really confusing.
Have you read the basic [documentation on data and file storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)?

Basically consider your app can write and read files that it created inside internal storage or primary external storage on the folders that belongs to this app.
Reading from sdcard can be done but requires permission from the user.
Writing on sdcard can be done with limitations and is not so easy. It also requires user permission.
Media files can be handled by [MediaStore api](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) and if they are [inside the folders from your app it is easier](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#media).

If you want to store Media file on other folders different from the default media folders, then it is a little more difficult.

Please, define better what are your app flows and requirements in order to be easier for someone to help.

Comment: Thank you @logui for your time. My apps requires storing outside of app specific storage. But read the android doc on using media store. Still wasn't clear to me. Would love for an explaination on this. Thanks

Comment: Explanation on what @darul9061? What exactly do you want to know? Be more specific.

Comment: What I want to know is how to store and open a file outside of app specific storage using URI

Comment: @darul9061 But that is precisely what it is been explained in the documentation linked on my answer. Start by delimiting the scope. More precisely what kind of file do you need to handle? Is it an image? Another kind of media? A text file? Another kind of file? The proper method to do it, will depend on the answers to these questions.

Comment: Thank you @logui for your time. I appreciate it. It's a video actually

Comment: As blackapps already have told you in a comment before, you have to use [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) to do this, since video, audio and images are Media. My advice is, read carefully this documentation and if you fill that this is not enough, search for more specific questions on stackoverflow (as blackapps also commented before) there are plenty of those on stackoverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923329/save-and-insert-video-to-gallery-on-android-10) for example.

Comment: Thank you @logui for your time. Appreciated 