# How to add video to Media Store database?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediastore, scoped-storage

I have saved a video in **getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)**
path in the android private directory. I want to show the video file in the gallery. I have tried **MediascannerConnection.scanFile** but it did not work.
Is there any altermative?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57940620/13533028 please refer to this link it might help you.:)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know

Answer (score 1):

you have to save your file in shared storage, for example, if u want to save pics, save them in /pictures folder or videos save them in videos folder

```
//for pictures
 contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/your app folder");
//for videos
 contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + "/your app folder");
```

P.s, this issue rises in scoped storage only, i.e sdk > 28 so start using scoped storage

[Give this a read (Storage changes in android 11)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaStore api to load a video from the gallery.

```
        // Represent the downloads collection
        Uri downloadsCollection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { // if sdk is 29 or higher
            downloadsCollection = MediaStore.Downloads.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        } else { // if sdk is lower than 29
            downloadsCollection = MediaStore.Downloads.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        /** Represents the list of which columns to return from query */
        String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.HEIGHT,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.DownloadColumns.SIZE
           };

        /** Initializing the selection file types to select from the gallery */
        String selection = MediaStore.DownloadColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "=" + MediaStore.DownloadColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        /** Initializing the order to sort the gallery by - date added descending */
        val orderBy = MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

        // Querying the gallery files collection, with the projection columns, the selection, and the order to sort by
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, null, orderBy);
           
        /** Represents the id column */
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns._ID)

        /** Represents the width column */
        int widthColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.WIDTH)

        /** Represents the height column */
        int heightColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.HEIGHT)

        /** Represents the display name column */
        int displayNameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)

        /** Represents the date added column */
        int dateAddedColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)

        /** Represents the size column */
        int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.SIZE)

        /** Represents the path to the file on disk column */
        int filePathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DATA)

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { // While there are files in the gallery
            /** Represents the id of the current file */
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)

            /** Represents the value which is the uri related file local path */
            val filePath = it.getString(filePathColumnIndex)

            /** Represents the display name of the current file */
            val displayName = it.getString(displayNameColumn)

            /** Represents the width of the current file */
            val width = it.getInt(widthColumn)

            /** Represents the height of the current file */
            val height = it.getInt(heightColumn)

            /** Represent the date added of the current file in milliseconds */
            val dateAdded = it.getLong(dateAddedColumn)

            /** Represents the size of the current file */
            var size = it.getLong(sizeColumn)

            /** Represents the uri of the current file */
            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(downloadsCollection, id)

            // todo: you can create a model object that will save all these values and then add it to a list
        }
```

This code is for loading all videos from the downloads collection, if you want a specific one you can change the value of the `selection` variable to match only the specific video.

After retrieving the desired content uri, you can load the video thumbnail into an `ImageView` using Glide:

```
Glide.with(context).load(contentUri).into(imageView)
```

Or just use a `VideoView` and set the content uri as the video uri to play the video.

Answer (score -1):

```
getExternalFilesDir()
```

is a private location for your app.

The MediaStore will not scan files from that location.

And hence no Gallery app will know about them as Gallery apps query the MediaStore.